# How can I align to center my button in CSS?

Tags: css

I have the following button in CSS, and I can't align it to center:

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #44c767;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #18ab29;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 16px 64px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
```

And when it goes to center, I want it to go a little bit lower(bottom).

Comment: Please share also your HTML code.

Comment: If the button is the only child of it's parent, put `text-align:center` on the parent, since the button is of inline level.

Answer (score 0):

Centering the button???

**1. Horizontally center the button inside a parent?**

You can use `display: flex; justify-content: center` on parent element.

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.btn {
  background-color: #44c767;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #18ab29;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 16px 64px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

OR You can also use `text-align: center` on parent element.

```css
.parent{
  text-align: center;
}
.btn {
  background-color: #44c767;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #18ab29;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 16px 64px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

**2. Vertically center the button inside a parent?**

You can use `display: flex; align-items: center` on parent element.

```css
.parent{
  height: 100vh;
  background: #f00;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.btn {
  background-color: #44c767;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #18ab29;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 16px 64px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

**3. Horizontally and Vertically center the button inside a parent?**

You can use `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center` on parent element.

```css
.parent{
  height: 100vh;
  background: #f00;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.btn {
  background-color: #44c767;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #18ab29;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 16px 64px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

**=> Move the button a little-bit-lower inside a parent as well as keeping it slightly centered?**

You can use `margin-top: 5vh;` on button.

```css
.parent{
  height: 100vh;
  background: #f00;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.btn {
  margin-top: 50vh;
  background-color: #44c767;
  -moz-border-radius: 28px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 28px;
  border-radius: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #18ab29;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 16px 64px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #2f6627;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```